# Supervisord does not send signal to all the processes simultaneously

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have a docker container which runs the supervisor daemon. Whenever the docker container receives a SIGTERM, I want to gracefully shutdown all the processes that supervisor is running. Supervisor by default will send a SIGTERM initially and will wait for 10 seconds. If the process does not exit, it will give it a SIGKILL. I wanted to give more time to these processes. I found the following on the supervisor docs

```
stopwaitsecs

The number of seconds to wait for the OS to return a SIGCHLD to supervisord after the
program has been sent a stopsignal. If this number of seconds elapses before supervisord  
receives a SIGCHLD from the process, supervisord will attempt to kill it with a final SIGKILL.
```

**I assume that supervisor will send the first signal to all the processes simultaneously.**
But this is not happening. The behaviour I observed is that it sends a SIGTERM to one of the process and until it is killed(after stopwaitsecs), none of the other processes receive the first signal.

The dockerfile, supervisor config and the program I am using are as follows.
Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip jq

RUN mkdir -p /opt/program/



WORKDIR "/opt/program/"
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

ADD ./ /opt/program/
RUN cp /opt/program/collector_supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
CMD  ["bash", "-c", " supervisord -c /opt/program/collector_supervisor.conf"]
```

Supervisor's config

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:prog1]
command=/usr/bin/python3 -u /opt/program/program.py
environment=PYTHONPATH=/opt/program/
stopwaitsecs=10
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:prog2]
command=/usr/bin/python3 -u /opt/program/program.py
environment=PYTHONPATH=/opt/program/
stopwaitsecs=10
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:prog3]
command=/usr/bin/python3 -u /opt/program/program.py
environment=PYTHONPATH=/opt/program/
stopwaitsecs=10
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Program.py

```
import logging
import time
import os
import sys
import signal

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
def shutdown_handler(*args):
    logging.info("%s SIGTERM", os.getpid())
    for i in range(10):
        logging.info("Shutdown handler. Process %s, %s th second", os.getpid(), i)
        time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        logging.info("from process %s", os.getpid())
```

Comment: Can you run the three processes in three separate containers, avoiding supervisord?  Does it help at all to remove the `bash -c` wrapper and use the JSON-array form of `CMD`?

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I want all the processes to be within the same container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to thank user `kevinkreiser` on [this](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/723) thread. Following are his words.

I found a workaround for at least my issue of not signalling shutdown at the same time, perhaps it also addresses the the OPs issue about starting/restarting as well I havent verified it. What you can do is you can use grouping in your supervisord config (ie. `[group:x]`). I have found that if you do this signals will indeed hit all processes at the same time.

Specifically, if you take my example above and add to the end of your config:

```
[group:some_group_name]
programs=prog1,prog2,prog3
```